# Sale, vale y dale ¿Hay algo detrás de su parecido?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, interjecciones

Sólo me parece curioso que, por poner tres ejemplos de paises que quedan a los extremos de la región hispanohablante, en España se diga *¡vale!*, en Argentina *¡dale!* y en México *¡sale!* (al menos en la connotación de asentimiento, las tres coinciden):

> A: Voy a tomarte una cerveza del refrigerador
>   B: ¡Ah vale/sale/dale!

¿Hay algún origen concreto detrás de su forma parecida `*ale`?

Comment: Nunca he escuchado *sale* en este contexto (tendría que venir *salar*, ¿no? pero... *salar* en Méjico significa causar mal azar).  También se puede escuchar *dale* en España sin problema.  Para mí en este contexto, *vale* es como, "Está bien (que lo hagas)" mientras *dale* es más bien "Hazlo".

Comment: En España nadie usaría "sale" en ese contexto, pero podrían usar "se sale", que significa que "mola" o "es lo más" (como _fuera de serie_ o _ se sale de las tablas_)

Comment: Dale, yo le doy, tu le das, "dale", adelante; continúa (Dale); no te rindas (Dale); Hazlo (Dale); Fuerza (dale); esos son algunos de los significados que "dale" tiene en castellano en el norte argentino. Palabra de uso muy común y coloquial, y probablemente muy antigua, pero sin embargo, hasta parece tan extraña a nuestro idioma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siendo sensatos, se trata de una coincidencia...

Pero si se me permite agregar una especulación bien forzada, podemos considerar que, a pesar de que *vale, sale* y *dale* tienen una función gramatical específica, en este caso se están usando como simples interjecciones.

*Vale* y *sale* no se usan como conjugaciones de valer y salir. *Dale* no es el imperativo de dar más el pronombre le. Son apenas vocalizaciones que dan a entender que la comunicación ha estado funcionando satisfactoriamente, okey, claro, mmm, sí pue...

Y no son las únicas interjecciones terminadas en -le:

> órale, híjole, éjale, ¡sale y vale!, ándale

Tal vez la terminación -le nos resulta "cómoda" para vocalizar, cuando no es necesario dar mensajes complejos.

O puede ser que necesitemos personalizar las exclamaciones agregando un pronombre de tercera, gramaticamente superfluo pero con algún valor connotativo, tal como hace la terminación *it!* en los insultos de angloparlantes, que aluden a un "ello" desconocido.

Comment: Ya (+1), pero "Okey, claro, etc." tienen todas su origen. Y, contario a tu respuesta, yo supongo que *sale* sí lo tiene en el verbo *salir.*

Answer (score 3):

This question has often plagued me as well.  I don't have a definitive answer for you, but I might be able to free-write my way into a helpful explanation.

### Sale, vale, and dale

Although I have never used `Dale` in this group of contextual words, I'll just assume it extends this idea.

In English, when we understand something, or we want to say yes without saying `yes`.. or pretty much anything at all, we say `Uh-huh`, `Mhmm`, `Ahh`.. Which are very similar to saying `Ok`, `right`, `yep`, and so on.  They all emphasize an affirmation.  Often, such an affirmation is an indicator for the speaker to continue.

> Speaker : I'm going to need 4 beers, 3 cups,....
>
> Listener : Mmhmm (sale)
>
> Speaker : 2 straws.... .....
>
> Listener : ... uh-huh (vale)
>
> Speaker : ....and 1 bottle of rum.
>
> Listener : Gotcha! (dale)

The words can also be used to question someone's understanding

> Speaker : In order to shoot the gun, it needs to have a bullet.  Got it? (vale)
>
> Speaker : The bullet is the key to shooting guns.  Understand? (sale)
>
> Speaker : After the next traffic light, make a left, Ok? (dale)

---

As far as the reason for using the verbs: valer, salir, and dar for the base of these words; I can only guess.

---

They most definitely have their regional usages, though I am unsure which ones are used where.  I am not a native speaker, and I have only ever been to Mexico; other than my own country.  While studying in Mexico, our teacher would often say `¿Sale vale?` after one of her educational statements.  I questioned her about it one time, while she was explaining the use of `sale`, `vale`, `dale`...  She answered saying that she wanted to be sure to use both to avoid any confusion...  essentially translating her `sale vale` into

> Got it? Good!